# how to set listener for image in FXML (Javafx Project)?

Tags: image, javafx, eventhandler

How to set an event handler for image inside the fxml. I've written the following which are 3 images and I want to click on them and they call the function I have already created in my controller class . I've already tried onMouseClick and onAction neither of them would work .

```
   <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0"  pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" >
            <image >
       <Image url="@/views/add.png" />
        </image>
        </ImageView>
     <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0"  pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
            <image>
       <Image url="@/views/remove.png" />
        </image>
        </ImageView>
     <ImageView fitHeight="31.0" fitWidth="29.0"  pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <image>
       <Image url="@/views/edit.png" />
        </image>
        </ImageView>
```

I've also checked out other post as well but they all say how to do it when the image is defined pragmatically .
Any suggestion is appreciated .

Comment: Why don't you opt to use a button, styled for images with CSS? I think using an ImageView to fulfill the purpose would be an overkill in a longshot.

Comment: @iMan is it possible  to simply add the css to fxml inline ? if yes I would appreciate a simple sample of doing so :)

Comment: I've already found it ;) Sample : <Button  mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" style="-fx-background-color: red;"/>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `onAction` because `ImageView`, is not really a clickable component, but nothing stops you from listening to its mouse events, so you can use `onMousePressed` or `orMouseClicked`. Additionally, settings `pickOnBounds` to true ensures that events will be fired even if you click on the transparent part of the image. Here is an example FXML file:

```
<ImageView onMousePressed="#imageClicked" pickOnBounds="true">
    <image>
        <Image url="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png"/>
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

And the corresponding method in its controller:

```
@FXML
public void imageClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Clicked: "+event.getSource());
}
```

Result:

> Clicked: ImageView@7bf40ff6[styleClass=image-view]

Comment: my output is :  Error resolving onMousePressed='#imageClicked', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script. :D

Comment: @DanialKosarifa You need to use a controller with the `imageClicked` method and make sure to import `javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent`, not some other `MouseEvent` class. Furthermore the `@FXML` annotation is not needed for `public` methods. @Dth It would be easier to reproduce the result, if you used a url on the web, e.g. http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png (the stackoverflow logo; use `pickOnBounds="true"` in this case, since the image is partially transparent).

Comment: @fabian indeed it makes much more sense to do it this way, thank you, I've edited my answer.